# How to import gensim summarize

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nlp, gensim

I got gensim to work in Google Collab by following this process:

```
!pip install gensim
from gensim.summarization import summarize
```

Then I was able to call `summarize(some_text)`

Now I'm trying to run the same thing in VS code:

I've installed gensim:
`pip3 install gensim`

but when I run

```
from gensim.summarization import summarize
```

I get the error

```
Import "gensim.summarization" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

I've also tried `from gensim.summarization.summarizer import summarize` with same error. Regardless I haven't been able to call the function `summarize(some_text)` outside of Google Collab.

Comment: Note: when using `inline formatting`, single backticks are fine. Triple backticks work, but they are more effort to write, and more fiddly to edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `summarization` code was removed from Gensim 4.0. See:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#12-removed-gensimsummarization

> ##### 12. Removed `gensim.summarization`
>
> Despite its general-sounding name, the module will not satisfy the
> majority of use cases in production and is likely to waste people's
> time. See [this Github
> ticket](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2592) for
> more motivation behind this.

If you need it, you could try:

- installing an older gensim version (such as `3.8.3`, the last official release in which it remained); or…
- copy the source code out to your own local module

However, I expect you'd likely be disappointed by its inflexibility and how little it can do.

It was *only* extractive summarization - choosing a few key sentences from those that already exist. That only gives impressive results when the source text was already well-written in an expository style mixing high-level overview sentences with separate detail sentences. And, its method of analyzing/ranking words was very crude & hard-to-customize – totally unconnected to the more generic/configurable/swappable approaches used elsewhere in Gensim or in other text libraries.

Answer (score 4):

So I had to download specifically

```
pip3 install gensim==3.6.0
```

I was using gensim==4.1.0 and this function no longer seems to work in this later version

Comment: If choosing to roll-back to an older Gensim, you'd probably prefer to get `gensim=3.8.3`, the latest version that still had the `summarization` module - rather than the even-older `3.6.0`.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Do you know why they removed it? It seemed to work well. Oh never mind. I see you posted the link!

Comment: My answer & the linked project issue talk about some of the reasons it was removed. If it's working well for you, that's great. I suspect some variant of the algorithm could someday return to Gensim, if the code were improved to integrate better with the rest of the project, and had an engaged contributor/maintainer.

Comment: @gojomo do you have any recommendations on libraries in Python that do a better job at summarization than the older GenSim models? I'm curious about what else is out there that might be better

Comment: There's been a lot of progress in deeper-neural-network language models, but I don't know the space well enough to recommend anything. Via an HN post about a Chrome extension (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=28322429), I'd heard recently about a free summarization model based on the BERT language model which appears usable in Python - see https://huggingface.co/sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6, which also offers a test text box. That may be worth looking into, directly, or as a jumping-off point to other related work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much - will take a look at that